# S.T sequence $(x_n)$ defined by recursion formula $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{3x_n}$, $x_1$=1 converges to 3

Tags: real-analysis

I proved that it's convergent.But I have a doubt in proving its limit.
I thought like this.

Let $x_n$ converges to $0$.Then for every $\varepsilon>0, x_n$ should satisfy the condition $|x_n-3|<\varepsilon$ for some $k, n\geq k$.

i.e,$3-\varepsilon<x_n<3+\varepsilon$.
$x_n$ is bounded above by $3$.So the inequality holds and thus proved.

Is it wrong?

The given solution is,let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{3x_n}$

$\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{3x}$

How did that become like that?

Comment: Because $\lim x_{n+1} = \lim x_n$ as $n\to \infty$ if the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges. The equation $x=\sqrt{3x}$ implies that $x=0$ or $x= 3$. As $x$ cannot be $0$, $x$ must be $3$.

Comment: @Yathiraj Sharma It didn't occur to me then.Thanks.Also,is the one I thought of wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate your explanation. Are you trying to prove that limit is not $0$ or are you proving that the limit is $3$ through the inequality you have mentioned?

Comment: You did not show that $x_n$ is bounded by $3$, and this is not a sufficient condition for convergence. Hence your answer is not satisfactory.

Comment: @Yathiraj Sharma I was trying to prove that limit is 3 as it's bounded by 3.But seems like that condition wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Oh ok.I forgot to include that proof.Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \space x_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \space x_{n+1}$ and since the sequence converges, we can set $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \space x_n = L$.

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{3x_n} \Longrightarrow L = \sqrt{3L} \Longrightarrow L^2-3L=0 \Longrightarrow L=0 \quad Or \quad L=3$$
And since the sequence is increasing and $x_1=1$, $L$ must be greater then $1$, thus $L=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Assuming $x_k\gt 0$ we have

$$
\ln(x_{k+1})=\frac 12(\ln 3+\ln(x_k))
$$

or

$$
u_{k+1}=\frac 12 u_k + c
$$

This recurrence has as solution

$$
u_k = 2^{-k}c_0 + 2^{-k}(2^k-1)2c = \ln x_k
$$

then

$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\ln x_k = 2c
$$